# On the action of superconformal generators in maximally supersymmetric Yang-Mills

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, superconformality

Consider maximally supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory in 3+1 dimensions.  This theory has 32 supercharges: 16 ordinary ones, conventionally labeled $Q$; and 16 superconformal ones, conventionally labeled $S$.  I can find the action of the usual supercharges $Q$ on the ${\mathcal N}=4$ vector multiplet in many places,  for example (3.2) of [D'Hoker and Freedman's review](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253), or (5.3), (5.4), and (5.5) of [Minwalla's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712074).  Can someone explain and/or provide a good reference for how the superconformal generators $S$ act on the vector multiplet?